# Multiple installations of Postgres on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-10

This is the first time I am setting up multiple Postgres postgres servers on Ubuntu 12.04LTS. (I know multiple versions is a bad idea, but need to sanity check new installation before I migrate and kill the old instance)

- Original Postgres V9.1 is installed using bundled apt-get install. (Port : 5432)
- New Postgres V10 is installed via EnterpriseDB package. (Port : 5433)

I am able to use standard utilities for the V9.1 like psql, pg_dump, etc. However, I am not able to access psql of V10. Instead I am getting this error message (note the incorrect port):

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/10/bin$ ./psqlpsql.bin: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I would like to be able to manage both ideally by using psql.

I usually use Python to connect to databases and I am able to create an SQLAlchemy connection to new instance at port 5433. I can query pg_catalog and information_schema as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The default port of postgres is 5432.
So If you want to access psql of V10, use the below commands:

`export PATH=/opt/PostgreSQL/10/bin:$PATH
 psql -p 5433`